Alternatives to solar panels/shingles?
Are solar panels the only option for running appliances without use of the power grid?
As someone with an apartment, I have a decent-sized balcony, but not enough to lay out an array of solar panels.
Are there other more compact technologies or is it just solar panels and solar shingles?

What's your end goal? Sustainability, or resilience in the event of a power outage? The answer to that will make a big difference as to what your solution should be.

The obvious alternative would be to get some variety of vertical-axis wind turbine (lower footprint and more bird-safe than the traditional horizontal-axis ones), provided you have good consistency of wind speed where you live. AFAIK it helps a lot if your balcony is at one of the corners of the building, but you could check by measuring with some kind of anemometer for a while to get a sense of what productivity you might expect.
There's ongoing development into "omnidirectional" rotor/propeller designs that should be particularly well suited for the erratic wind directions in urban environments. If your apartment building isn't in the middle of nowhere by any chance, you should look specifically for some "omnidirectional" design (not sure if any of them are market-ready yet), as it should provide better performance than what you might find in existing studies, which were probably based on traditional designs only.
Another option for efficiency is paradoxically an older but nowadays less popular design option: making the tower and rotor blades entirely out of wood. A big reason modern designs face a bigger challenge breaking even is that the complex materials they're made of are very expensive. A wooden rotor pays for itself much faster and can even be more durable long-term.

As far as I've read, trying to generate electricity from wind energy at home is not economical as one can expect only very little production in most cases.

A google search for 'balcony solar' will show that it is possible to buy solar panels which can be vertically mounted on the front of a balcony, and which either feed into a battery, or, in some cases, to the mains wiring of the apartment (I don't really understand how this works, but some do seem to offer it). These wouldn't take up any of the floor space on the balcony itself.


Are solar panels the only option for running appliances without use of the power grid?

No.
The options are:

Solar panels, connected to a battery, and an inverter
Gas/diesel-powered generator (gas is lighterweight and cheaper to buy, but more expensive to run at part load)
Only a battery that you charge from the grid whenever grid is available, and an inverter

If your interest is in handling power outages, maybe a huge LiFePO4 battery with an inverter could handle that. Tesla's powerwall is one example of the technology but I'm not a fan of that. It's overpriced and doesn't have all that much battery capacity. You can't connect more batteries to it if you want. So a better option would be to construct a huge 40 kWh 48V battery bank from LiFePO4 batteries and then use an inverter/charger like Victron MultiPlus. However, if you at all have the possibility of running a generator (needs a large outdoor area), a generator is handy protection against outages, since 20 kilograms of fuel have more energy than 20 kilograms of batteries. I wouldn't run a generator on a balcony, though: it may be a fire risk if the balcony is made of wood, and balcony may be too close to the apartment, meaning carbon monoxide gases may get in to your home.
If your interest is in sustainability, a battery help massively even if you don't have solar power connected to it. You can charge the battery at times when grid electricity is sustainable (and therefore cheap if you have a spot priced contract), and discharge it at times when peaker fossil fuel power plants are running (and therefore grid electricity has a huge cost).
If your interest is just hatred against the grid and a desire to cut the grid connection, don't: grid power is a huge bargain. Use it!
